# Maven:adding dependencies and spring bean configuration file into the jar file

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I created the Spring Standalone Application,In that project i have the Java Classes,Spring Configuration File(applicationContext.xml) and the pom.xml file which contains the spring dependencies.

**And this is the Structure of my project:**

```
ExampleProject
|-- src/main/java
    |--org.example
       |--java Classes(MainApp.java)
|-- applicationContext.xml
|-- src/main/resource
|-- src
|-- target
|-- pom.xml
```

**Problem:**
But my problem is when creating the jar file using the Maven Assembly plug-in it is adding only the maven dependencies and java class but not the spring configuration file.Can you provide me the good solution for adding the dependencies and spring bean configuration file into the jar file

**Below is the pom.xml for your reference**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.iton.createjarProject</groupId>
<artifactId>createjarProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins> <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </execution>

</executions>
</plugin>


<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
  </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
      <mainClass>SimpleKeyLogger</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

        </plugins>


</build>


</project>
```

Comment: By configuration file you mean to say the `applicationContext.xml` ? Also what is in your `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 2):

The [Maven convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) is that application resource files (such as the Spring context file) should be placed in `src/main/resources` - unless this has been explicitly redefined in the `pom.xml`. Maven will pick up anything in this folder and place it into the artifact when packaging the app.

So move your `applicationContext.xml` to `src/main/resources` (and it should be called src/main/**resources** not src/main/**resource**)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution...It was working...If any doubts i will add comments